# linq outer join and group by

Tags: linq, group-by, outer-join

I am quite new to linq and trying to convert an inner join to an outer join query, but cant get it to work.

The current query looks like this -

```
(from learnerRating in DbContext.LearnerRatings
  join rating in DbContext.Ratings on learnerRating.RatingId equals rating.Id
  join lesson in DbContext.Lessons on learnerRating.LessonId equals lesson.Id
  join user in DbContext.Users on lesson.UserId equals user.UserId
  where user.CentreId == centreid
  group rating by rating.Name into sectiongroup
  orderby sectiongroup.Count() descending
  select new ChartPointsViewModel
  {
        ValueStr = sectiongroup.Key,
        Value = sectiongroup.Count(),
        order = sectiongroup.Max(r => r.Id)
 }).OrderBy(rc => rc.order);
```

But if there is no learnerrating then i dont get the rating back.  So i wanted to do a left outer join on rating and learner rating, but this is where all of my paths fail.  I reordered it to do the outer join

```
from rating in DbContext.Ratings
     join learnerRating in DbContext.LearnerRatings on rating.Id equals learnerRating.RatingId into learnratingsjoininner
```

But how do i then join the other data to filter out only users in a centre and then group?

I can get the query working without the filter -

```
(from rating in DbContext.Ratings
     join learnerRating in DbContext.LearnerRatings on rating.Id equals learnerRating.RatingId into learnratingsjoininner                                
     from lrinner in learnratingsjoininner.DefaultIfEmpty()
     //where learnerRating.Lesson.User.CentreId == centreid
    group rating by rating.Name into sectiongroup

    select new ChartPointsViewModel
    {
           ValueStr = sectiongroup.Key,
           Value = sectiongroup.Count(),
           order = sectiongroup.Max(r => r.Id)
    }).OrderBy(rc => rc.order);
```

But how do i add the filter

```
where learnerRating.Lesson.User.CentreId == centreid
```

Comment: where learnerRating.Lesson.User.CentreId = centreid use single "=" maybe and give information about error pls

Comment: If i add: where lrinner.Lesson.UserId == 1 then this produces the correct result.  If I add:  where lrinner.Lesson.User.CentreId == 1 then i receive nothing back.  I wonder if there is a problem with my model navigation linkage.